# Wsdl curl error 7: couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, linux, curl, wsdl, nusoap

I have a PHP website on a linux server.
I am using `nusoap` function from `nusphere` website for connecting to a eservice gateway.
I had no problem for a few months with it, but recently i got the following error.

```
Error: wsdl error: Getting https://www.something.com:27635/eservice.asmx?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 7: couldn't connect to host
```

I contacted to my linux host server and ask them for telnet the address and the port 27635.
and below is the result

```
root@ns3 [~]# telnet www.something.com 27635
Trying 212.80.nn.nn...
Connected to www.something.com (212.80.nn.nn).
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

root@ns3 [~]# wget https://www.something.com:27635
--2012-10-23 10:54:46--  https://www.something.com:27635/
Resolving www.something.com... 212.80.nn.nn
Connecting to www.something.com|212.80.nn.nn|:27635... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4740 (4.6K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.1'
```

It seems the connection is ok.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You tried wget from commandline. But as it is curl, try as well curl from commandline. And also some curl from within PHP. It might be that it will just not work from inside PHP. Make use of the verbose option then to troubleshoot. As well check for the curl errors, it normally tells you what is going on behind the scenes to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: Your tests aren't equivalent. A webserver may happily serve up one particular url and barf up rotten bits on another url on the same server. your wget test just fetches the root page of the service site, NOT the service url you're trying in curl.

Comment: Telnet and wget are commands which my host guys run at the server.
I am not familiar with curl statement and i am using `nusoap`standard program for connecting to my eservice.
How can i use verbose option in my PHP program to turn on curl debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! i found the solution.

A few weeks ago i changed some of my PHP programs for using gzip compression.

I had inserted `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` at the start of the programs, but i had forgotten to put `ob_flush()` at the end of them.

So there was some nested output buffering.

There was no problem with all programs except than my WSDL eservice program which uses CURL.

It generated curl error 7 or 28.